# How to convert from Cartesian J2000 coordinates to Cartesian Galactic coordinates?

Tags: galaxy, coordinate

I'm using a star database (the [HYG database](http://www.astronexus.com/hyg)) which has xyz positions and velocities for the stars. This has +X towards the vernal equinox, +Z towards north celestial pole, +Y towards Right Ascension 6 hours and it's based on J2000 and centered on the sun.

I'd like to convert these to a Cartesian Galactic coordinate system centered on the sun, with +X pointing to its center and +Z angled so that it shoots out of the galactic plane on the north side.

This should just be a simple rotation, but after a lot of searching I can't seem to find the rotation to use, nor some way of converting it through a third system.
Does anyone know how to obtain the correct rotation matrix here? (or some other method of rotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform an equatorial $(x, y, z)$
into a galactic $(x_G, y_G, z_G)$, the
[Gaia data release 1 documentation, section 3.1.7](https://gaia.esac.esa.int/documentation//GDR1/Data_processing/chap_cu3ast/sec_cu3ast_intro.html#SS7), uses

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_G \\ y_G \\ z_G\end{bmatrix}
= \mathbf{A}'_G
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}
$$

where

$$
\mathbf{A}'_G = \begin{bmatrix}
{−0.054876} ~ {−0.873437} ~ {−0.483835} \\
{+0.494109} ~ {−0.444830} ~ {+0.746982} \\
{−0.867666} ~ {−0.198076} ~ {+0.455984}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is composed of three coordinate frame rotations
$$
\mathbf{A}'_G = \mathbf{R}_Z(-l_\Omega)
~ \mathbf{R}_X(90^\circ - \delta_G)
~ \mathbf{R}_Z(\alpha_G + 90^\circ)
$$
with the north galactic pole at equatorial coordinates
$(\alpha_G = 192.859^\circ, \delta_G = +27.128^\circ)$
and the galactic equator crossing the celestial equator at galactic longitude
$l_\Omega = 32.932^\circ$.

This is equivalent to the transformation defined in the
[Hipparcos catalogue](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/hipparcos/catalogues), volume 1, section 1.5.3.

[Murray 1989](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1989A&A...218..325M) and
[Liu 2011](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2011/02/aa14961-10/aa14961-10.html)
give similar matrices whose elements differ after 6 decimal places, which matters only if you require sub-arcsecond precision.

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm this formula seems to be correct based on the results

Comment: For completeness, the Gaia DR2 documentation [also includes this transformation](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/documentation/GDR2/Data_processing/chap_cu3ast/sec_cu3ast_intro/ssec_cu3ast_intro_tansforms.html#SSS1), but it looks like its the same as used for DR1.